# Using FragmentContainerView with Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-layout

After updating to Navigation [2.2.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.2.0-beta01) from the previous version, lint gives a warning about replacing the `<fragment>` tag with `FragmentContainerView`.

However, replacing the tag alone seems to prevent the navigation graph from being inflated.

According to [2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.2.0-alpha01), `FragmentContainerView` is used internally. Should we ignore the lint warning?

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Lint warning: "Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView. -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main"/>

    <!-- other elements -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `FragmentContainerView`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky See official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView

Comment: @EugenPechanec Why do we need that when we have Jetpack Navigation?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Good question, Jetpack Navigation navigates between fragments. Fragment _transitions_ (enter/exit animations) behave differently when the fragments are in `FragmentContainerView` and in any other container layout. The differences are described in FCV documentation linked above. Basically, FCV is supposed to make transitions work more as you would expect. Or, Jetpack Navigation depends on fragments. If Fragments are broken, you get new fixed Fragments library or wait for new version of Navigation which depends on new fixed Fragments.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I get what you're saying.  However, I think it is a nuisance for developers to keep up with two different API's, when Google has clearly advocated Jetpack Navigation exclusively...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Important!** There are known issues with different versions of `FragmentContainerView`. See the [changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0) before using. Read through bug fixes and use a recent version of the library.

---

For now, you should also declare dependency on Fragment 1.2.0-beta02 as it includes a fix for this use case.

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-beta02"
```

> #### Version 1.2.0-beta02
>
> October 11, 2019
>
> **Bug fixes**
>
> Fixed an issue where Fragment's `onInflate()` did not receive proper attributes from `FragmentContainerView`, breaking cases such as `NavHostFragment`. ([b/142421837](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142421837))

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0-beta02

Comment: @glend Please prepare a minimal project that reproduces the issue and report it on the official [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757). Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

There is still a bug that will throw an exception if you simply replace *fragment* for *<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>*. The fix, as of now, as stated by many google engineers in this [bug thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973) is to change your code in your activity:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: yes! only 2 these lines and all my navigation work again, no one additional change required

Comment: This answer should be made with the correct one.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 15):

The [NavigationBasicSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample) has been updated to 2.2.0-alpha01 but is still using the `fragment` tag. The [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) shows the use of the `FragmentContainerView`, but the nav graph is inflated in the code (they have several different graphs) and the corresponding host fragment is added to the `FragmentContainerView`. So I'd say at this time we should ignore the warning if we want automatic inflation.

Comment: I noticed this as well in the samples. It looks like adding the latest `Fragment` dependency takes care of the lint warning.

Comment: Why do we need FragmentContainerView?

Comment: I checked the code in AdvancedSample. It just makes me vomit! I don't know why Team at google has to create and break things in such awkward manner. Now I may have to copy the extension function Today but this might again break Tomorrow with some update in navigation library. It just sucks!!

Answer (score 5):

using Java

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Comment: This may be an answer, but adding further information will help the quality of your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Iam using AGP 8.4 kotlin 1.9.22

I fixed this by these step

toml version catalog

```ini
[versions]
navVersion = "2.7.7"

[libraries]
navigation-ui = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui", version.ref = "navVersion" }
navigation-dynamic-features-fragment = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment", version.ref = "navVersion" }
navigation-fragment = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment", version.ref = "navVersion" }
navigation-fragment-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navVersion" }
navigation-ui-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navVersion" }
```

gradle app level

```
// change ktx when your activity or fragment using kotlin
implementation libs.navigation.fragment // .ktx
implementation libs.navigation.ui // .ktx
implementation libs.navigation.dynamic.features.fragment
```

in `MainActivity`

```java
// imports
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

// onCreate
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        // make the fragment switcher works
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
```