# FragmentContainerView and app:navGraph - This navigation graph is not referenced to any layout files

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

To prevent Lint warning (replace `fragment` with `FragmentContainerView`) after upgrading to latest fragments (1.2.2 version) and navigation (2.2.1 version) I replaced fragment with `FragmentContainerView`

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    ....
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

But after that I found error in my `@navigation/nav_graph` - This navigation graph is not referenced to any layout files

Everything works fine, but that error is very annoying.

Comment: Looks like we need just ignore this error as I see the same error for navigation graphs on https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Im using latest stable => AS 3.6.0 and 3.6.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using FragmentContainerView with Navigation component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320487/using-fragmentcontainerview-with-navigation-component)

Comment: @Rule, Unfortunately, does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that I understand this wrong, but if everything works, this might be a classic case of Android Studio being in need of some cache clearing and restarting. Maybe even manually deleting build folders from your project.

Comment: No, I tried clean/sync gradle/refresh/invalidate and etc. Error disappears only when I revert FragmentContainerView back to fragment. Looks like classic google fails with "stable" libs :) For now, I just suppress error with tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the latest versions of the navigation-fragment-ktx in your build.gradle(app)

```
def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same "false" warning, seems it will be fixed in a future release. Meanwhile, as Android Studio suggests, the warning can be safely ignored using:

```
<navigation
    ...
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error however, the app compiles fine and works. I suppose we have to wait for fix in the next stable release.